# How can I use C++11 variadic templates to define a vector-of-tuples backed by a tuple-of-vectors?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a bunch of vectors:

```
vector<int> v1;
vector<double> v2;
vector<int> v3;
```

all of the same length. Now, for every index i, I would like to be able to treat (v1[i], v2[i], v3[i]) as a tuple, and maybe pass it around. In fact, I want to have a a vector-of-tuples rather than a tuple-of-vectors, using which I can do the above. (In C terms, I might say an array-of-structs rather than a struct-of-arrays). I do not want to effect any data reordering (think: really long vectors), i.e. the new vector is backed by the individual vectors I pass in. Let's .

Now, I want the class I write (call it `ToVBackedVoT` for lack of a better name) to support any arbitrary choice of vectors to back it (not just 3, not int, double and int, not every just scalars). I want the vector-of-tuples to be mutable, and for no copies to be made on construction/assignments.

If I understand correctly, variadic templates and the new `std::tuple` type in C++11 are the means for doing this (assuming I don't want untyped `void*` arrays and such). However, I only barely know them and have never worked with them. Can you help me sketch out how such a class will look like? Or how, given

```
template <typename ... Ts>
```

I can express something like "the list of template arguments being the replacement of each typename in the original template arguments with a vector of elements of this type"?

**Note:** I think I might also want to later be able to adjoin additional vectors to the backing vectors, making an instance of `ToVBackedVoT<int, double, int>` into, say, an instance of `ToVBackedVoT<int, double, int, unsigned int>`. So, bear that in mind when answering. This is not critically important though.

Comment: `additional column to the table` meaning a new type in the tuple?

Comment: Do you want the underlying storage to be like an array of structs, or a struct of arrays?  This matters in terms of efficiency at least, and depends on  your use cases.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I guess the whole purpose of his design is to have a struct of arrays for better efficiency, but he wants to have a nice access in the *style of* array of structs.

Comment: You could write an iterator wrapper around an arbitrary number of vectors. This wrapper is *only* used to iterate through the set of vectors, nothing more. This way you can have a lot of "columns" in your table but have several different iterator wrappers using a different set of columns each (similar to simple "views" in SQL on the same table). Would that be a nice option for you?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It is like leems suggests. Clarified my question about this point.

Comment: @leemes: I need arbitrary element access, not just iteration. But, if you can point me to code for an iterator, that would be a start I suppose.

Comment: Random access iterators can help with that.

Comment: @leewangzhong: If I have a random access iterator, and backing storage, I can just implement my vector-of-tuples class using that...

Comment: @Koushik: See my clarified answer.

Comment: I'm trying this, and I'm getting stuck on returning a variadic tuple of references. The only solutions I can think of are probably more typing than you're saving, and the whole solution can take more cycles than copying a bunch of ints and floats. Oh, and one other idea is to fake a tuple...

Comment: I'm also currently at it. Seems to be a tricky thing ;) @leewangzhong `std::tie` ;)

Comment: I'm using `tuple_cat` to build the structure, but I can't figure out how to use `tie` to concatenate references on the way out.

Comment: Wait, to use it as a tuple, wouldn't it be more annoying? `get<0>(myvot[i])` instead of `get<0>(mytov)[i]`, or just `myget(mytov,i,0)` and `mytie(mytov,i) = 1,2.0,3`?

Comment: @leewangzhong: I'll have code which takes a single tuple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One idea is to keep the *storage* in the "struct of array" style in form of vectors for good performance if only a subset of the fields are used for a particular task. Then, for each kind of task requiring a different set of fields, you can write a lightweight wrapper around *some* of those vectors, giving you a nice random access iterator interface similar to what `std::vector` supports.

Concerning the syntax of variadic templates, this is how a wrapper class (without any iterators yet) could look like:

```
template<class ...Ts> // Element types
class WrapMultiVector
{
    // references to vectors in a TUPLE
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>&...> m_vectors;

public:
    // references to vectors in multiple arguments
    WrapMultiVector(std::vector<Ts> & ...vectors)
        : m_vectors(vectors...)    // construct tuple from multiple args.
    {}
};
```

To construct such a templated class, it's often preferred to have a template type deducting helper function available (similar to those `make_{pair|tuple|...}` functions in `std`):

```
template<class ...Ts> // Element types
WrapMultiVector<Ts...> makeWrapper(std::vector<Ts> & ...vectors) {
    return WrapMultiVector<Ts...>(vectors...);
}
```

You already see different types of "unpacking" the type list.

Adding iterators suitable to your application (you requested in particular random access iterators) is not so easy. A start could be forward only iterators, which you might extend to random access iterators.

The following iterator class is capable of being constructed using a tuple of element iterators, being incremented and being dereferenced to obtain a tuple of element *references* (important for read-write access).

```
class iterator {
    std::tuple<typename std::vector<Ts>::iterator...> m_elemIterators;

public:
    iterator(std::tuple<typename std::vector<Ts>::iterator...> elemIterators) 
        : m_elemIterators(elemIterators)
    {}

    bool operator==(const iterator &o) const {
        return std::get<0>(m_elemIterators) == std::get<0>(o.m_elemIterators);
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator &o) const {
        return std::get<0>(m_elemIterators) != std::get<0>(o.m_elemIterators);
    }

    iterator& operator ++() {
        tupleIncrement(m_elemIterators);
        return *this;
    }
    iterator operator ++(int) {
        iterator old = *this;
        tupleIncrement(m_elemIterators);
        return old;
    }

    std::tuple<Ts&...> operator*() {
        return getElements(IndexList());
    }

private:
    template<size_t ...Is>
    std::tuple<Ts&...> getElements(index_list<Is...>) {
        return std::tie(*std::get<Is>(m_elemIterators)...);
    }
};
```

For demonstration purposes, two different patterns are in this code which "iterate" over a tuple in order to apply some operation or construct a new tuple with some epxression to be called *per element*. I used both in order to demonstrate alternatives; you can also use the second method only.

1. `tupleIncrement`: You can use a helper function which uses meta programming to index a single entry and advance the index by one, then calling a recursive function, until the index is at the end of the tuple (then there is a special case implementation which is triggered using SFINAE). The function is defined outside of the class and not above; here is its code:

   ```
   template<std::size_t I = 0, typename ...Ts>
   inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
   tupleIncrement(std::tuple<Ts...> &tup)
   { }
   template<std::size_t I = 0, typename ...Ts>
   inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
   tupleIncrement(std::tuple<Ts...> &tup)
   {
       ++std::get<I>(tup); 
       tupleIncrement<I + 1, Ts...>(tup);
   }
   ```

   This method can't be used to assign a tuple of references in the case of `operator*` because such a tuple *has* to be initialized with references immediately, which is not possible with this method. So we need something else for `operator*`:
2. `getElements`: This version uses an index list (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036110/592323) which gets expanded too and then you can use `std::get` with the index list to expand full expressions. The `IndexList` when calling the function instantiates an appropriate index list which is only required for template type deduction in order to get those `Is...`. The type can be defined in the wrapper class:

   ```
   // list of indices
   typedef decltype(index_range<0, sizeof...(Ts)>()) IndexList;
   ```

More complete code with a little example can be found here: http://ideone.com/O3CPTq

**Open problems are**:

- If the vectors have different sizes, the code fails. Better would be to check all "end" iterators for equality; if one iterator is "at end", we're also "at end"; but this would require some logic more than `operator==` and `operator!=` unless it's ok to "fake" it in; meaning that `operator!=` could return false as soon as *any* operator is unequal.
- The solution is not const-correct, e.g. there is no `const_iterator`.
- Appending, inserting etc. is not possible. The wrapper class could add some `insert` or and / or `push_back` function in order to make it work similar to `std::vector`. If your goal is that it's syntactically compatible to a vector of tuples, reimplement all those relevant functions from `std::vector`.
- Not enough tests ;)

Comment: `std::tuple<std::vector<Ts...>&> m_vectors;` Is this string right?

Comment: Good catch; I fixed this in ideone but didn't "backport" it ;) Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: I didn't know about `typename std::vector<Ts>::iterator...`. Gonna start misusing that right away!

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to all the variadic template juggling is to use the `boost::zip_iterator` for this purpose. For example (untested):

```
std::vector<int> ia;
std::vector<double> d;
std::vector<int> ib;

std::for_each(
  boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(ia.begin(), d.begin(), ib.begin())
    ),
  boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(ia.end(), d.end(), ib.end())
    ),
  handle_each()
  );
```

Where your handler, looks like:

```
struct handle_each :
  public std::unary_function<const boost::tuple<const int&, const double&, const int&>&, void>
{
  void operator()(const boost::tuple<const int&, const double&, const int&>& t) const
  {
    // Now you have a tuple of the three values across the vector...
  }
};
```

As you can see, it's pretty trivial to expand this to support an arbitrary set of vectors..

Comment: I need to use boost more often. Simply awesome.

Comment: Can we then simply do `for (const auto& tup : make_zip_iterator(
    make_tuple(ia.begin(), d.begin(), ib.begin()))` ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I don't believe so, as the full range needs to be available (i.e. the ends of each vector have to also be provided as a tuple), which is why you have to rely on algorithms such as `for_each`

Comment: @Nim: Ah, of course.  I was thinking (but not writing!) about a version of make_zip_iterator that would take the sequences directly and call begin()/end() on them internally, then expose its own begin()/end().  I guess that's a little too froofy for most C++ folks though.

Comment: I love Boost. I giggle everytime I see something in the lines of "sure, the 137th-B rear tube fires just the rocket you want, and it's a single button too !", and it's the case every. Damn. Time.

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like:

```
#if 1 // Not available in C++11, so write our own

// class used to be able to use std::get<Is>(tuple)...
template<int... Is>
struct index_sequence { };

// generator of index_sequence<Is>
template<int N, int... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

template<int... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> { };

#endif

// The 'converting' class
// Note that it doesn't check that vector size are equal...
template<typename ...Ts>
class ToVBackedVoT
{
public:
    explicit ToVBackedVoT(std::vector<Ts>&... vectors) : data(vectors...) {}

    std::tuple<const Ts&...> operator [] (unsigned int index) const
    {
        return at(index, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
    }
    std::tuple<Ts&...> operator [] (unsigned int index)
    {
        return at(index, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
    }

private:
    template <int... Is>
    std::tuple<const Ts&...> at(unsigned int index, index_sequence<Is...>) const
    {
        return std::tie(std::get<Is>(data)[index]...);
    }

    template <int... Is>
    std::tuple<Ts&...> at(unsigned int index, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::tie(std::get<Is>(data)[index]...);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>&...> data;
};
```

And to iterate, create an 'IndexIterator' like the one in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20272955/2684539

To adjoin additional vectors, you have to create an other `ToVBackedVoT` as `std::tuple_cat` does for `std::tuple`

Comment: Why the use of `int` in the template arguments?

Comment: The `int...Is` is used to unpack `std::get<Is>(data)` as `std::get<0>(data), .., std::get<N - 1>(data)`. `gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>` is `seq<0, 1, 2, .., sizeof...(Ts) - 1>`. It is a way to iterate over tuple index.

Comment: Wow you're revising all your answers to make them C++1y compatible? o.O

Comment: Since it may be a while before this is usable, why not also mention the substitute for `index_sequence`?

Comment: @leewangzhong: I don't use `std::index_sequence` (as it is not available in C++11), I Implement a similar custom version with same name to ease the transition to C++1y.

Comment: Oh, hm. I missed that you included it.

Answer (score 2):

From asker's clarification on how this would be used (code that takes a tuple), I'm going to propose this instead.

```
//give the i'th element of each vector
template<typename... Ts>
inline tuple<Ts&...> ith(size_t i, vector<Ts>&... vs){
    return std::tie(vs[i]...);
}
```

---

There's a proposal to allow parameter packs to be saved as members of classes ([N3728](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3728.html)). Using that, here's some untested and untestable code.

```
template<typename... Types>
class View{
private:
    vector<Types>&... inner;

public:

    typedef tuple<Types&...> reference;

    View(vector<Types>&... t): inner(t...) {}

    //return smallest size
    size_t size() const{
        //not sure if ... works with initializer lists
        return min({inner.size()...});
    }

    reference operator[](size_t i){
        return std::tie(inner[i]...);
    }
};
```

And iteration:

```
public:
    iterator begin(){
        return iterator(inner.begin()...);
    }
    iterator end(){
        return iterator(inner.end()...);
    }

    //for .begin() and .end(), so that ranged-based for can be used
    class iterator{
        vector<Types>::iterator... ps;
        iterator(vector<Types>::iterator... its):ps(its){}
        friend View;

    public:

        //pre:
        iterator operator++(){
            //not sure if this is allowed.
            ++ps...;
            //use this if not:
            //  template<typename...Types> void dummy(Types... args){} //global
            //  dummy(++ps...);
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator--();
        //post:
        iterator operator++(int);
        iterator operator--(int);
        //dereference:
        reference operator*()const{
            return std::tie(*ps...);
        }
        //random access:
        iterator operator+(size_t i) const;
        iterator operator-(size_t i) const;
        //need to be able to check end
        bool operator==(iterator other) const{
            return std::make_tuple(ps...) == std::make_tuple(other.ps...);
        }
        bool operator!=(iterator other) const{
            return std::make_tuple(ps...) != std::make_tuple(other.ps...);
        }

    };
```

Comment: +1 Great, that first bit allowed me to randomly access a series of vectors like that.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to a std::tuple of vectors (vector::iterators):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// identity
// ========

struct identity
{
    template <typename T>
    struct apply {
        typedef T type;
    };
};

// concat_operation
// ================

template <typename Operator, typename ...> struct concat_operation;

template <
    typename Operator,
    typename ...Types,
    typename T>
struct concat_operation<Operator, std::tuple<Types...>, T>
{
    private:
    typedef typename Operator::template apply<T>::type concat_type;
    public:
    typedef std::tuple<Types..., concat_type> type;
};

template <
    typename Operator,
    typename ...Types,
    typename T,
    typename ...U>
struct concat_operation<Operator, std::tuple<Types...>, T, U...>
{
    private:
    typedef typename Operator::template apply<T>::type concat_type;
    public:
    typedef typename concat_operation<
        Operator,
        std::tuple<Types..., concat_type>,
        U...>
    ::type type;
};

template <
    typename Operator,
    typename T,
    typename ...U>
struct concat_operation<Operator, T, U...>
{
    private:
    typedef typename Operator::template apply<T>::type concat_type;
    public:
    typedef typename concat_operation<
        Operator,
        std::tuple<concat_type>,
        U...>
    ::type type;
};


// ToVectors (ToVBackedVoT)
// =========

template <typename ...T>
struct ToVectors
{
    private:
    struct to_vector {
        template <typename V>
        struct apply {
            typedef typename std::vector<V> type;
        };
    };

    public:
    typedef typename concat_operation<to_vector, T...>::type type;
};

// ToIterators
// ===========

template <typename ...T>
struct ToIterators;

template <typename ...T>
struct ToIterators<std::tuple<T...>>
{
    private:
    struct to_iterator {
        template <typename V>
        struct apply {
            typedef typename V::iterator type;
        };
    };

    public:
    typedef typename concat_operation<to_iterator, T...>::type type;
};


int main() {
    typedef ToVectors<int, double, float>::type Vectors;
    typedef ToVectors<Vectors, int, char, bool>::type MoreVectors;
    typedef ToIterators<Vectors>::type Iterators;

    // LOG_TYPE(Vectors);
    // std::tuple<
    //     std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >,
    //     std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >,
    //     std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >

    // LOG_TYPE(Iterators);
    // std::tuple<
    //     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >,
    //     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >,
    //     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >
}
```

Comment: I don't see in your solution how that helps OP. And your `concat_operation` seems more complicated than needed. `template <template <typename> class Operator, typename... Ts> struct concat_operation
{
 typedef std::tuple<typename Operator<Ts>::type...> type;
};` seems enough.

Comment: It seems also that your `concat_operation` cannot be used with `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative similar to  `boost::zip_iterator` I wrote a `zip` function with a very simple interface:

```
vector<int> v1;
vector<double> v2;
vector<int> v3;

auto vec_of_tuples = zip(v1, v2, v3);
```

For example, iterate over these tuples:

```
for (auto tuple : zip(v1, v2, v3)) {
    int x1; double x2; int x3;
    std::tie(x1, x2, x3) = tuple;
    //...
}
```

Here, `zip()` takes any number of ranges of any type. It returns an adaptor which can be seen as a lazily evaluated range over a tuple of elements originating from the wrapped ranges.

The adaptor is part of my [Haskell-style functional library ***"fn"***](https://bitbucket.org/leemes/fn) and implemented using variadic templates.

Currently **it doesn't support modification** of the original ranges' values via the adaptor because of the design of the library (it's intended to be used with non-mutable ranges like in functional programming).

A **brief explanation** on how this is done is: `zip(...)` returns an adaptor object which implements `begin()` and `end()`, returning an iterator object. The iterator holds a tuple of iterators to the wrapped ranges. Incrementing the iterator increments all wrapped iterators (which is implemented using an index list and unpacking an incrementing expression into a series of expressions: `++std::get<I>(iterators)...`). Dereferencing the iterator will decrement all wrapped iterators and pass it to `std::make_tuple` (which is also implemented as unpacking the expression `*std::get<I>(iterators)...`).

P.S. Its implementation is based on a lot of ideas coming from answers to this question.

Comment: Doesn't your example code incur an unnecessary assignment from the tuple to the three variables?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes it does, but I don't know how to do the same conveniently with references. You can do `int &x1 = get<0>(tuple);` but that looks complicated and you can introduce errors with the indices, in particular when you change the tuple / zip. Sadly, you can't do `int &x1; ...; tie(x1) = ...` since that would leave the reference uninitialized, and the assignment doesn't "reseat" the reference. If C++ had "native" tuples (they considered it), I'm sure something like `for(auto & (x1,x2,x3) : zip(v1,v2,v3))` would be possible.