# Does boost offer make_zip_range?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, tuples, commutativity

At [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703588/1593077) here on SO, there's a comment suggesting a useful C++ construct, similar to `make_zip_iterator`, but for ranges: It takes a tuple of ranges and produces a new range - whose `begin()` and `end()` iterators are the appropriate zip iterators.

Now, this should not be too difficult to implement, but I was wondering - Isn't already offered already by Boost somehow?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11 - I don't know of Boost offering this, but that thread shows you how to use Boost to build it.  It'd be nice to have it built in somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boost.Range is providing `combine()` function as `zip_iterator`'s range.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html

Comment: ... and will it work with C++11 range-based for loops, or do I need to stick to BOOST_FOREACH ?

Comment: You can apply to both (range-based for and BOOST_FOREACH).