# boost::combine, range-based for and structured bindings

Tags: c++, for-loop, boost, c++17

Is there a way to make `boost::combine` work with structured bindings and range-based for (so that identifiers in the structure binding actually point to containers' elements instead of nested tuples of whatever `boost::combine` uses under the hood)? The following ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02edc1d5780626f4)) fails to compile:

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> b{2,3,4};

    for (auto [f, s] : boost::combine(a, b))
    {
        std::cout << f << ' ' << s << std::endl   
    }
}
```

Comment: The above example surprisingly compiles under MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/M8GEsqqbE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real answer is to use either `boost::tie` or grab the range-v3 `zip()` which actually yields a `std::tuple`.

---

The for educational purposes only answer is just to adapt the structured bindings machinery for `boost::tuples::cons`. That type already has a `get()` which works with ADL and does the right thing, so all we need to do is provide `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` (which ends up being really easy to do since these exact traits already exist in Boost):

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    struct tuple_size<boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
        : boost::tuples::length<boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
    { };

    template <size_t I, typename T, typename U>
    struct tuple_element<I, boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
        : boost::tuples::element<I, boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
    { };
}
```

But don't actually do that in real code, since really only the type author should opt-in to this kind of thing.

That'll make the structured binding just work.

Comment: yep, thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Strange, why this is not a part of the standard?

Comment: @h22 because `boost` isn't part of `std`

Comment: Do you mean, there is no way to add this somehow bypassing the std:: namespace? I was thinking about just take and include this as part of my project. But some FUD remains within me, so I have decided to ask a separate question on that first. Other ways to iterate over multiple vectors I have seen so far add more complexity than remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::tie` to accomplish this.

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> b{2,3,4};
    int f, s;
    for (auto var : boost::combine(a, b))        
    {
        boost::tie(f, s) = var;
        std::cout << f << ' ' << s << std::endl;   
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f00f99f983f33a5c).

Comment: I would like to use structured bindings to avoid pre-defining `f` and `s`.