# Why boost::combine support for structured bindings is missing the adaptation of the structured bindings machinery for boost::tuples::cons?

Tags: c++, for-loop, boost

This does not work out of box:

```
std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
std::vector<int> b{2,3,4};

for (auto [f, s] : boost::combine(a, b)) {
    std::cout << f << ' ' << s << std::endl;
}
```

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585723/boostcombine-range-based-for-and-structured-bindings) contains a quite small fragment of C++ code that suddenly makes this to work.

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    struct tuple_size<boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
        : boost::tuples::length<boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
    { };

    template <size_t I, typename T, typename U>
    struct tuple_element<I, boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
        : boost::tuples::element<I, boost::tuples::cons<T, U>>
    { };
}
```

The author, however, advises against using it in production.

Can this fragment crash my code under any circumstances, or it is just some organizational reason not to use this way to iterate over the loop?

Comment: Rule of Dumb: Don't provide specialization you don't own for classes you don't own.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this fragment crash my code under any circumstances, or it is just some organizational reason not to use this way to iterate over the loop?

If an update to boost adds specialisations like those, your program might suddenly break.

The likely scenario is that boost adds equivalently specialised specialisations, and the breakage is a compile time error.

Another scenario is that something else in boost starts using that specialisation, and you end up with different translation units using different partial specialisations for identical instantiations. This makes your program ill-formed (no diagnostic required)

> [[temp.class.spec]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#1)
>
> A partial specialization shall be declared before the first use of a
>   class template specialization that would make use of the partial
>   specialization as the result of an implicit or explicit instantiation
>   **in every translation unit** in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is
>   required.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 1):

> Can this fragment crash my code under any circumstances, or it is just some organizational reason not to use this way to iterate over the loop?

It could possible crash it, but what it does do is offer a point for your code to have undefined behavior.  You don't "own" boost so you don't dictate what specializations of things in the standard boost may provide.  If, at some point in the future boost decides to add this support, which very well may happen, then you now have two definitions of  `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` which is an ODR violation.  Not only is it undefined behavior, but no diagnostic is required so you may never even know something is wrong until it manifest itself in some strange and obscure way.