# Boost zip-iterator and structured bindings

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, structured-bindings

I was messing around with a wrapper class for "structure of arrays" and ended up finding "boost-iterators's" zip-iterator. Now I was wondering if there's a way to make the resulting tuple from iterating, work with structured bindings like in the commented code segment below. I found this post [boost::combine, range-based for and structured bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585723/boostcombine-range-based-for-and-structured-bindings) but that didn't help me solve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Buffer2 final
{
    vector<T> xs, ys;

    auto begin() noexcept
    {
        return boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(xs.begin(), ys.begin()));
    }

    auto cbegin() noexcept
    {
        return boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(xs.cbegin(), ys.cbegin()));
    }

    auto end() noexcept
    {
        return boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(xs.end(), ys.end()));
    }

    auto cend() noexcept
    {
        return boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(xs.cend(), ys.cend()));
    }
};


int main()
{
    Buffer2<float> values;
    values.xs.resize(10);
    values.ys.resize(10);

    iota(values.xs.begin(), values.xs.end(), 0);
    iota(values.ys.begin(), values.ys.end(), 10);


    for (auto value : values)
    {
        cout << value.get<0>() << ' ' << value.get<1>() << '\n';
    }

    // This does not work ( x is head_type, y is tail_type )
    /* for(auto [x, y] : values) {
        cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
    }*/
}
```

Comment: "but that didn't help me solve it" What didn't help you solve it? This seems like the same question as the linked question - in what way does it not work?

Comment: [Works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/GjEEsp) ?